# Split unicode string into list of character strings

Tags: java, unicode

How to split unicode string containing surrogate-pair characters and normal characters into a `List<String>` of characters?

(`String` is required to store surrogate-pair characters consisting of two `char`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
String s = "ac";
List<String> result = List.of(s.split("(?<=.)"));
for (String e : result)
    System.out.println(e + " : length=" + e.length());
```

output:

```
 : length=2
a : length=1
 : length=2
c : length=1
 : length=2
```

## Code points

Or, use a stream of [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

```
List<String> result = 
    s
    .codePoints()                    // Produce a `IntStream` of code point numbers.
    .mapToObj(Character::toString)   // Produce a `String` containing one or two java chars for each code point in the stream.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/96pX8M).

To capture the code points, use this variation of the above code.

```java
List<Integer> codePointNumbers = 
    s
    .codePoints()            
    .boxed()       
    .collect( Collectors.toList() ) ;
```

When run:

> codePointNumbers.toString(): [128522, 97, 128102, 99, 128522]

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's easier to use `List<Integer>` storing codepoints instead.

Comment: @cdalxndr Yes, I highly recommend you **focus on code point** integer numbers to represent individual characters. The `char` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent most Unicode characters. Juggling `char` values to represent modern Unicode text is frustrating and unnecessary. Look for several code point oriented methods added to `String` and `Character` classes. I added another code example to this Answer showing how to collect code point integers.